# Why array is not working on object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

**HTML**

```
<div class="one_in"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one_in{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**JS**

```
var ar = ["one_in", "two_in", "three_in"]; 
var colors = {
    ar[0]: 'blue',
    ar[1]: 'green',
    ar[2]: 'red'
};
x = document.getElementsByClassName('one_in');
for (var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++ ){
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x[i].className];
}
```

How to use the array `ar`'s value `"one_in", "two_in", "three_in"` inside the object so my div get automatically colored in `blue` `green` `red` respectively

http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAYMJN2T8KU2

Comment: Why not just use the array values directly as the object keys?

Comment: Object expects keys as static string. Try `var colors = {}; color[ar[0]] = 'blue'` This will create a dynamic property named `one_in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap it with `[ ]`.

```
var colors = {
    [ar[0]]: 'blue',
    [ar[1]]: 'green',
    [ar[2]]: 'red'
};
```